# Upload Zip from google Codemagic to Microsoft Appcenter

Tags: powershell, devops, cicd, codemagic, appcenter

I am trying to upload Artifacts Zip from Codemagic to Appcenter using a built-in environment using a Post-publish script

```
appcenter distribute release --group QC  --file "${zipPath}"  --release-notes 'App submission via Codemagic' --app CASHIN/INTRO-WINDOWS --token "" --build-version "1.0.${PROJECT_BUILD_NUMBER}" --quiet
```

PROJECT_BUILD_NUMBER not work

Comment: Try removing the `$` sign inside the bracket: `${$PROJECT_BUILD_NUMBER}`

Comment: Same Issue
appcenter distribute release --group QC  --file "${zipPath}"  --release-notes 'App submission via Codemagic' --app CASHIN/INTRO-WINDOWS --token "" --build-version "1.0.${PROJECT_BUILD_NUMBER}" --quiet

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? you can add `set -x` in post-publish script to see what exact commands are executed